# C - use of a volatile pointer

Tags: c, keyword, volatile

Why would one create a **volatile** pointer? And suppose I want a **volatile** pointer which points to a **volatile** variable, which of the following declarations would accomplish this:

```
volatile int *pData;
```

or

```
volatile int * volatile pData;
```

Comment: You are aware of reasons to make a variable volatile?

Comment: @Yunnosch as far as I know it is used to tell the compiler that the variable can change at any time and therefore it must be kept in memory.But I'm not sure why anyone would use a volatile pointer

Comment: Surely your instructor expects you to either (i) refer to your lecture notes; (ii) consult your recommended reading; or (iii) think about it for yourself.  If (iii), then you should at least be able to present *something* of your line of thought.

Comment: @John I already did that, and I already read a couple articles on the subject, I'd just like to know the applications of a volatile pointer

Comment: What in your opinion is the relevant difference between a variable and a pointer variable, which would make the use of a volatile variable sensible but not a volatile pointer variable?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_(computer_programming)

Comment: many programmers BELIEVE `volatile` is kind of ... `sychronized` 'atomic' or 'protected between threads'. Nope. This is ONLY "please not optimise to registers".

Comment: To be clear: `volatile int *pData;` is not a `volatile` pointer.  The 2nd is a [pData as volatile pointer to volatile int](https://cdecl.org/?q=volatile+int+*+volatile+pData%3B)

Comment: @JacekCz Your definition is far from accurate as well.

Comment: @EugeneSh. agree, this is planned simplification. Answer below show required use of 'critical section' (pattern also has few names), OK

Comment: One way to reveal the meaning of your posted  code (and most declarations of data) is to read the declaration from right to left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why would one create a volatile pointer?

Example: To access data whose pointer is updated by a background process.

```
Stuff * volatile VideoFrame;
for (;;) {
  Block_Changes();
  Stuff MyCopy = *VideoFrame;
  Allow_Changes();
  Use(&MyCopy);
}
```

> I want a volatile pointer which points to a volatile variable, which of the following declarations would accomplish this:

The 2<sup>nd</sup> meets the goal. `volatile int * volatile pData;` is a:
 [pData as volatile pointer to volatile int](https://cdecl.org/?q=volatile+int+*+volatile+pData%3B)

---

The 1<sup>st</sup> `volatile int *pData;` is a non-volatile pointer to volatile data:
  [pData as pointer to volatile int](https://cdecl.org/?q=volatile+int+*+volatile+pData%3B)

The `volitle` keyword  is most often used in this context. [@ Eugene Sh.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46737944/c-use-of-a-volatile-pointer/46738513#comment80423974_46738513)

Answer (score 0):

One reason to use the modifier `volatile' is so the compiler does not optimize the variable out of existence.

Another reason to use the modifier 'volatile' is so when ever the code references that variable, it accesses the actual variable and not the value left in some register.

Another reason to use the modifier 'volatile' is when the variable value can change outside the control of the current program.  For instance a hardware register or when an 'interrupt' updates the variable that your application is reading.